# Unreacheable Statement in Android

Tags: android

I am new in android and I was trying to create a simple app using the online tutorial for making single touch paint app. which has the following code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

But during running the app i got the error calling unreacheble statement for invalidate(); statement what i am missing please help me figure it out.

ERROR:

```
Note: E:\android_projects\Closertotheedge\app\src\main\java\yubrajpokharel\com\closertotheedge\Game.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:(53, 9) error: unreachable statement
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Your switch is complete including default:return - meaning no line after will be called.  Remove the default: case if you want the invalidate() to always happen.

Comment: thanks a lot #Raanan

Answer (score 1):

In your switch block each case returns that is why all code below cannot be reached

Comment: Thanks u so much #donfuxx it is solved now. that was a silly mistake i didn't noticed

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 `case`s in your switch statement, each one of them has a `return` statement (including the `default`) because of this there is no path into the `switch` that doesn't result in the function returning.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can remove the inner return in at least one of the `case`s.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which branch of the switch statement your app takes, it will always return, meaning that the invalidate command will never be run (since returning from a method ends that method's execution).

To fix that, don't return true in your switch statement - only do that after you call invalidate(). You should be able to leave the return false in there, since that will catch any other events that don't need to invalidate the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the statement `return false;` from **default case**.